# S3:getObject() for Graphql

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, graphql

Any help would greatly appreciate since this is my first time ever using AWS services.

So I am using the Apollo server and Graphql for the query/mutation. I have managed to upload my images to the S3 bucket.

```
Mutation: {
   uploadToS3: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
      const { createReadStream, filename, mimetype, encoding } = await args.file;
      const stream = createReadStream();
      const pathName = path.join(__dirname, `../public/images/${filename}`);
      stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(pathName))
            .then(upload(pathName, filename))
            .catch(error => { console.log(error) });
}
```

Basically using Apollo Server File Upload I have managed to upload my image to the /public/images folder. Then after the file has been uploaded I then upload that file to the S3 bucket.

Here is the upload function from above

```
// uploads a file to s3
function upload(pathName, filename) {
    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(pathName);

    const uploadParams = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Body: fileStream,
        Key: filename
    }

    return s3.upload(uploadParams).promise();
}
```

```
The biggest problem I am facing is displaying that image from S3 to React App. 

I found the URL from AWS https://<bucketName>.s3.amazonaws.com/<imageFile>

However, I got the:

<Error>
   <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
   <Message>Access Denied</Message>
   <RequestId>G3C79X8WGN3SFR</RequestId>
   <HostId>8RApYRDn565zy6ic8f8ZDqLKQx/IcLtz26NDHiLpc0Q566k6BbRB7z47WKHnYMpKDkz9gFVgc=</HostId>
</Error>
```

So the solution I found is S3.getObject()

```
// download a file from s3
function getFileStream(fileKey) {
    const downloadParams = {
        Key: fileKey,
        Bucket: bucketName
    }

    return s3.getObject(downloadParams).promise();
}
```

But I got back this

```
{
  AcceptRanges: 'bytes',
  LastModified: 2021-06-03T02:54:55.000Z,
  ContentLength: 0,
  ETag: '"d41d8cd98f00b204e98098ecf8427e"',
  ContentType: 'application/octet-stream',
  Metadata: {},
  Body: <Buffer >
}
```

I can't, or at least don't know how to use that to display the image to React through Graphql query/mutation.

Could anyone help me figure out how to write a Graphql query to fetch the image from S3 so I can use that query in React to display the data?

Again, any help, or documentations, or advice would greatly appreciate since I have been stuck for nearly 3 days

Answer (score 1):

you can return the buffer as a base64 encoded string to the frontend.

```
data.Body.toString('base64');
```

then add the image as a data-uri in the html.

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
    9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="sunrise" />
```

I have tested the code below and it returns me a base64 string of the image.

```
import { S3 } from 'aws-sdk';
import { GetObjectOutput } from 'aws-sdk/clients/s3';


const s3 = new S3({ region: 'ap-southeast-2'});

(async () => {

  const file: GetObjectOutput = await s3.getObject({
    Bucket: 'getobject103',
    Key: 'sample.jpeg'
  }).promise();

  console.log(file.Body.toString('base64'));

})()
```

In addition to the code above, I just wanted to illustrate you how I tested it with a screenshot.

[image]

Another solution is to use s3-presigned URL. Basically you use AWS credential(that has permissions to access the s3 object) from a backend service(such as express) and generate a pre-signed url. you can use the presigned url as the image url in the html. Remember, each presigned url generated gives access to a single image.

> All objects by default are private. Only the object owner has permission to access these objects. However, the object owner can optionally share objects with others by creating a presigned URL, using their own security credentials, to grant time-limited permission to download the objects [Sharing an object with a presigned URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)

[how to generate s3 presigned url in nodejs[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59426408/accessing-aws-s3-signed-url-via-node-js-express/59426566#59426566)

Comment: Thank you Arun K, for replying I was overjoyed when I see your solution. However, for some reason when I tried 

data.Body.toString('base64'); 

it returns empty, not undefined but empty strings. I can see a couple of empty string lines in the console. Do you know why it does that?

Here is what I wrote in my Graphql
Query : {
getImages: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
const readStream = await getFileStream(key);
console.log(readStream.Body.toString('base64');
}
}

Comment: It returns me a base64 string. Updated my answer with code and an illustrated screenshot. Please compare your code and let me know. You can see that the image is displayed in the terminal when I piped the base64 string output to the imgcat command :)

Comment: Yep, you are correct Arun K, after 1 full day of debugging and code changing, I have found the issue, it turns out, my upload function is wrong, well not wrong but Apollo Server File Upload does work and I am able to upload to S3. However, all my files are 0B Size, I thought it was normal but after 24 hours something snaps in my head, and I did a little more digging it turns out, files shouldn't be 0B Size when uploaded to S3, so I manually uploaded one and ran the ".Body.toString('base64')" and it turned the result very similar to yours. So I am now working on upload function to fix the issue

Comment: Happy to help. You can try presigned URL approach too. It’s a popular method as well